# Get circumference without just measuring edges

Tags: vertices, edges, measurement

I need a way to get the circumference of a "complex" face. When I use the MeasureIt tool, the circumference appears much larger because of the vertex clusters (highlighted in yellow). I have been doing it manually by modifying a circle so that is fits within the face, then using the measure it tool, which works. However, I need a way to automate this process eventually and I am not sure how I would incorporate that into an add on. I have tried to do an inset, I have also tried merging by distance but then it is last accurate. I would like a way to just have one vertex at the clusters. Hopefully the picture I attach provides some clarity. [image]

Also to clarify, I am not necessarily looking for python code, I can hopefully figure that out once achieving a simpler version to get the circumference. Any ideas, guidance on where to look more into, or solutions are all greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hello, why would clusters of points deviate the calculations of the circumference ?

Comment: it will add up the length of all the little edges (using Measureit tool), I can add a zoomed in picture. The circumference is roughly 60 m but Measureit calculates it as 75m

Comment: Which circle do you want? One that fits inside? One that captures all points? Something in between?

Comment: *»I need a way to get the circumference of a "complex" face.«* - and this is exactly what you get. If you want to calculate the circumference for a circle, it's radius multiplied by tau or $τ×r = 2π×r$ You can get the radius by e.g. taking a minimum from the distances of points to the average position of all points…

Comment: @RobinBetts either works as long as its clear. But I think making the elliptical shape through the inner most points would be ideal.

Comment: How many inner-most points, and by what logic to pick them?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady that is a question I do not know how to solve. If there was a way to average the points at these clusters and and replace it with a single vertex that would be great. Right now I am roughly modifying a circle to fit the ellipse, but it is not as accurate. What are your thoughts? Is there a tool to do so in Blender or will I have to play around with scripting? I am not sure

Comment: This way is "merge by distance" - you would need to explain why merge by distance wasn't working for you. You only said "then it is last accurate", but it is very cryptic: how is it less accurate? Apparently you know what result you're supposed to get and merging by distance moves you away from that result. Could as well be, that there are two stacked errors, 1st moves away from the good result in one direction, 2nd moves away the good result in the other direction, therefore canceling the 1st to a degree… Then merge by distance fixes the 2nd error therefore increasing the overall error...

Comment: Could also be that you don't understand your problem, and this is why merge by distance, by doing exactly what you want, is increasing the error. All in all this is not Blender problem and not even a programming problem, it's a design problem the way it is stated currently. And you don't share the logic to give an advice on it. One more idea is that maybe the smoothing (merging is kind of smoothing) is inevitably shrinking the shape, so maybe you need to represent the positions in polar coordinates, smooth that and convert back to cartesian…

Comment: I think you might have to rephrase this question. You want to fit an **ellipse** to  given set of points, not a circle?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you for taking the time to respond, I went back and saw that when I merged by distance, it was in the wrong order of magnitude so it was significantly decimating the geometry. I went back and it is working much better, and it is more accurate to the actual circumfrence. Hopefully this works for me to get to the next step, sorry about the confusion!

Comment: This is a very unusual problem. "I need a way to get the circumference of a "complex" face" - why? What's the context here?